# Static Library as a Pod, with Restkit dependency in podspec

Tags: ios, static-libraries, cocoapods

I have an in-house static library, that I'm moving to a Pod. The idea is that our main application uses this with Cocoapods as it will solve a lot of issues we are having within the team.

I've already created a new project using `pod lib create` ([here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html)) and migrated the code, models, everything. Seemed like a safer better process than setting up everything in the 2-year-old-messed-up project.

Now, the thing is that, the project is not compiling because I use Restkit. Perfect, I just add the `s.dependency 'RestKit', '~> 0.26'` line in my podspec file. Right?

But, what do I do now? How do I tell the project it has to actually download this dependency? Running `pod update|install` doesn't work because it runs agains the Podfile.

Should I be editing the project example Podfile? If so, how do I run tests inside my own library?

Hope I've made myself clear. Thanks in advance because this is driving me crazy!